# External links from admin backend crashing Magento

Tags: magento2, admin, email

I wanted to put some **external links on my magento 2 admin page** so users could easily **acess intranet, mail and google spreadsheets.**

I managed to get links in to the backend but as sooon as they were external the backend crashed and I couldnt login.

Is this a security measure? Can I work around it?

---

[image: my links area]

Its from http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_admin_menu_items/
When I try to change action into a link it breaks.

```
         parent="Pulsestorm_MenuTutorial::top_level_example"
         action="cms/page/index"
        />                            
    <!-- END:   new node -->                
</menu>
```

Comment: can you upload your code please...?

Comment: I updated my answer ... Check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use external link direct in `menu.xml` file.

**Use the following way to redirect external link :**

**menu.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Abc_Blog::view" title="Abc Blog" module="Abc_Blog" sortOrder="11" action="your controller path" resource="Abc_Blog::view"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

**Redirect.php (Controller File) :**

```
<?php
namespace Abc\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Grid;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
class Redirect extends Action
{
    protected $_redirect;  
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        RedirectInterface $redirect
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_redirect('https://google.com');
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 from my side , just quick question what if i need to open it in new tab ? when i click on admin menu external link needs to open in new tab ?

Comment: Happy to help sir @KakiSami ... Happy Coding :) !!

Comment: @ManthanDave Did you ever solve the New Tab issue?